# SpecFlow copy of runtimeconfig.json fails

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, integration-testing, specflow

When I build my Specflow solution, I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4651,5): error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "<myUser>\.nuget\packages\specrun.runner\3.1.48\tools\netcoreapp3.1\TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.Executor.anycpu.netcoreapp3_1.runtimeconfig.json" to "bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\SpecFlowPlusRunner\netcoreapp3.1\\TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.Executor.anycpu.netcoreapp3_1.runtimeconfig.json". Could not find a part of the path 'bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\SpecFlowPlusRunner\netcoreapp3.1\\TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.Executor.anycpu.netcoreapp3_1.runtimeconfig.json'.
```

I can see that the path is wrong, there are two `\\` instead of one but I have no idea where the path comes from. The solution worked until two hours ago and I haven't changed anything but code in it. Are there any VS or PC configurations/paths and where should I search for them?

Deleting `\obj`, `\bin`, `\.vs`, restarting VS, restarting PC, copying the files per hand, updating to another SpecFlow versions, and everything else I could think of didn't help. The file `Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets` hasn't been changed. I am able to build other Specflow solutions (with .NET Framework, I don't have others with .NET Core).

Any ideas?

**Update**

We tested on the PC of another colleague and the issue occurred there as well, so it is not a problem of my PC.

Also, I switched on the build logging and could see that all SpecRunner paths have the same issue with two `\\`

Comment: Which .NET Core version are you using in the affected project?

Comment: We have v.2.2.5 of the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core package. But it seems that all possible runtime configs are getting copied, no matter which .NET Core version one uses. If I knew how to switch that off, it would already help me but I don't find such a setting. I also updated the question with some more infos.

Comment: Î have the double \\ also in my logfiles, so I don't think this is a problem. Windows should be able to handle that.

Comment: I have 40 errors like this and no other error. And I have plenty of warnings related to the same. I have no idea what else could be the problem. But I will check if I can find something else...

Comment: 2 ideas. 1 Could you check if a new project created from our project wizard works for you?
2. what happens if you go back to previous changes. Does it then work again?

Comment: Btw, you are using NuGet packages for ASP.NET Core 2.2 in a .NET Core 3.1 project. No idea if this should work at all.

Comment: 1) The AspNetCore package has no newer versions, this one is compatible with everything after 2.2. 
2) Reverting to what worked before doesn't help, even with the old (once compiling) code I get the same errors. The only thing I can think about is some Windows update from the last days causing problems.
3) I haven't tried to create a new project yet, I am still looking at the build output. I will post an update once I've done that.

Comment: I already checked the build output and plenty of other things (like using .NET Framework instead of .NET Core) and it didn't help. I don't get any other warnings except these copy things, so I still think that they are causing the build failure.  I created a new project from scratch and I can build it.. but using the same SpecFlow and .NET SDKs doesn't help me to build my project. After spending 1.5 days on the issue I have to leave it, I can't loose more time on that. Thank you for the support anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2-3 days the problem disappeared. Without any changes on my side. My colleagues could also build the solutions. Quite strange but main thing is that it works now.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same error. Created my project in an above folder, it worked.

Seems like the filepath was too long.

Comment: It's not surprising when they have filenames like "TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.Executor.anycpu.netcoreapp2_1.runtimeconfig.json".